Angular frontend with ASP.NET Core Web API backend: 500 Internal Server Error in Chrome (works on localhost, not after publishing)
I am working on a project that uses Angular framework for the frontend and an ASP.NET Core Web API for the backend. The setup works perfectly in the localhost environment. However, after publishing, I encounter a 500 Internal Server Error in Chrome when calling an API. This issue doesn't occur in Edge or Firefox.
Additional details

I've set up CORS policies in .NET Core and allowed all origins.
Clearing Chrome’s cache and history temporarily resolves the issue, but it reappears when the published link is opened again in Chrome.
The problem only arises after deployment; locally, the API calls succeed without issues.

What might cause this 500 error in Chrome after publishing, especially when the API calls work on localhost?
Any insights on this issue would be highly appreciated.
Update
This is how I have setup CORS policy:
 var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

 builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
   {
       options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
           builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader());
   });

 var app = builder.Build();
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");


Unless you've done something to catch/handle exceptions in your .NET code, the web API will return an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error. Unfortunately, it typically won't give you anything more than that. You might want to add some middleware to wrap all API calls with exception handling to at least log exceptions to a file as a diagnostic aid.

Sometimes, allowing all origins (AllowAnyOrigin) can be problematic in production, as some security settings in browsers may interpret overly permissive CORS as a risk. Try setting specific allowed origins instead of AllowAnyOrigin. Besides, you can also try to use the "Network" tab in Chrome’s Developer Tools or Fiddler to inspect the request headers, responses, and check server logs in detail for the 500 error.

Since clearing Chrome’s cache temporarily resolves the issue, try setting cache control headers in the API responses to disable response caching: [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]. Refer to Response caching in ASP.NET Core.

Most Likely

I would double-check if the API calls use https and not HTTP. Generally, you could get away with using HTTP on localhost, but Chrome may reject it.

To dig deeper

If you're using Azure (assuming your backend is in C#), use Application Insight logs. (Rider has an extension that also shows logs locally that has saved me a lot of time: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13984-application-insights-debug-log-viewer)

use a try-catch block inside your API endpoint that wraps every action the controller tries to perform.


For example:
[HttpGet("/DoSomething")]
public async Task<ActionResult> DoSomething()
{

    try
    {
       //Your code goes here
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return e.message
    }
}

This approach is loosely similar to the service result pattern https://www.milanjovanovic.tech/blog/functional-error-handling-in-dotnet-with-the-result-pattern.
I'm not the biggest fan, but it is convenient

Unlikely the OP's problem is http vs https because a request using the wrong scheme won't even get to the application endpoint (HTTP 500 is symptomatic of error originating from endpoint code). Although wrapping each endpoint in a try/catch is a workable brute-force approach, same result could be achieved using middleware to cover all endpoints as a one-and-done change.
